# Using TLS/SSL trusted certificate improved performances

Tags: performance, ssl, go, https, tls1.2

We're developing a cloud-based service for businesses. The component I'm in charge of is divided in three parts, a simple *WEB* and *assets* server, an API server (both written in `Go`) and the actual *WEB* application (`AngularJS` based). The *WEB* application flow is pretty straightforward, it downloads assets and source files from the web server and datas from the API server.

Until yesterday we've been using a simple **Self-Signed SSL certificate** and I was blaming myself because the whole application was slow, and by slow I mean very slow (I didn't though about actually measuring it but it could take ~3/4 seconds to load assets and sources and a few more to load datas).

Yesterday we managed to start using a **Trusted SSL Certificate** (obtained via *Let'sEncrypt*) and all of a sudden I noticed that the performances have dramatically improved. It now takes (measured) less than 2 seconds to be fully loaded and ready to be used.

Now, I guess the actual reason is that, with a trusted Certification Authority and a valid SSL certificate, there are less security checks to be executed by the browser and/or during *TLS* handshake and thus less performance degradation in all requests.

But: Am I right or partially/completely wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: How, precisely (with what command line options) did you generate the self-signed certificate and the Let’s Encrypt certificate?

Comment: This looks rather strange. Have you changed anything else? Like the SSL configuration settings. Depending on the algorithms and supported protocol versions SSL/TLS can be more costly (not in the order of seconds btw).

Comment: @Zoyd I didn't generate it myself but I managed to get the command that has been executed to generate the certificate by using the docker container from quay.io/letsencrypt/letsencrypt. The arguments were: `letsencrypt --name certbot  certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges tls-sni` (nothing special AFAIK)

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti Nothing changed in configuration settings. The TLS handshake and SSL configuration is the standard provided by the Golang HTTP server.

Comment: So the Let’s Encrypt certificate uses the default values, assuming the config file in the Docker container does not override them. What about the self-signed certificate ?

Comment: @Zoyd The self signed one was an old certificate generated with standard openssl commands. It was generated in late 2015 and used wherever we needed a testing or demo environment with HTTPS. I can't recall the script used to generate it but it was a standard certificate with no particular configurations. 

Only noticeable thing was that the domain associated with the certificate was completely different from the domains the certificate actually was used for.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use HAproxy or Nginx as reverse proxy with ssl/tls and then direct the requests to your app. Something like https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-haproxy-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

This way you are supporting horizontal scaling.

Comment: We've already designed and prepared our proxying strategy for the production environment. The case in question is related to our staging environment where we do not have (or need) any proxy and each service handles the TLS handshake by itself.